# newman support for setNextRequest

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

As part of PostMan collection there's a request which does setNextRequest using the below snippet. This snippet executes fine via PostMan collection runner, however it fails when executed via newman cli it errors out with 'expected false to be truthy at assertion:1 in test-script inside "Get Position"'. Does newman support the setNextRequest api, any other suggestions to achieve the same.

```
var responseJSON;
var maxTime = new Date(pm.globals.get("$requestMaxTime"));
try { 
    responseJSON = JSON.parse(responseBody); 
    if(responseJSON.Code !== pm.globals.get("testCODE")) {
        if(maxTime > new Date()) {
           postman.setNextRequest("Delay");
        }
        else {
            tests["code is saved"] = responseJSON.Code === pm.globals.get("testCODE");
        }
    }
    else {
        tests["code is saved"] = responseJSON.Code === pm.globals.get("testCODE");
    }
}
catch (e) { }
```

Comment: What command do you use? Why are you using a mixture of the old and newer syntax?

Comment: Is there a downside to the mix and match, are there some known issues regarding this approach? Newbie query, how can the snippet be changed to newer method. 
Wrapped newman in a powershell script.

param([string]$CollectionPath, [string]$EnvironmentPath, [string[]]$DataPath)

newman run $CollectionPath -e $EnvironmentPath -d $DataPath

Comment: Depends how much rework that you would what to do when the older syntax eventually gets removed from the application. `pm.test` allows you to use `pm.expect` with the chaijs module, which is better in my opinion. Also, `pm.response.json()` will parse the body so no need to do what you're doing with it. What file are you using on the CLI for the globals?

Comment: It's a JSON file which has the data variables defined.

Comment: I understand that but you're not including in your Newman run script. I wasn't sure if that was the reason it wasn't working.

Comment: closing the thread, a bit of re-write with the newer syntax resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

if you write setNextRequest in your postman : it will execute successfully

postman.setNextRequest("");

once you export the test as Collection v2.1 (recommended):

json file will come as : "postman.setNextRequest(\"\");"

add to your newman test

run the test with command : newman run test.js

try that !!